# asp.net mvc wiki

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wiki, wiki-engine

I need to provide a wiki page for an app which would be like an island pretty much - little like codeplex wiki page

e.g.
  site/Products/Details/1/Wiki

site/Products/Details/99/Wiki

site/Products/Details/2423423/Wiki

site/Some-other/page/page-id/Wiki

If there's a master admin page, that'd be fanstastic but is not a requirement

Is there anything like above or similar or close enough ? or something that can be integrated *relatively* easily ?

Answer (score 10):

Fresh off the compiler, the CodePlex team has actually released their Wiki Parser today.  You can grab it here: [WikiPlex on Codeplex](http://wikiplex.codeplex.com/).  From that, it should be fairly easy to create a few tables in your DB for pages and revision history.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to take this product and conform it to your needs.  You either need an endpoint defined for each product (created with the creation of each product) or you need a layer on top of a wiki system to filter the view of the wiki information by product.

http://www.tavaresstudios.com/Blog/page/ASPNET-MVC-Wiki-Sample.aspx

Comment: ok, will take a look at that next week !
Is there a working solution that i could use to figure out the code ?